# How to add alert 'if data parameter = nil'

Tags: mysql, ios, uialertview, nserror

Hello I'm trying to create an Alert if i'm not able to connect to a web service. Essentially, if I see **'data parameter is nil'** then I would like an alert to say "not able to connect, and return.

This is the code I'm using for it.

```
- (IBAction)search:(id)sender
{


 if ([hostTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [passwordTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camaleon Alert" message:@"All fields must be filled in" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert show];


 }else{




NSString *requestStr = @"http://";
requestStr = [requestStr stringByAppendingString:hostTextField.text];
requestStr = [requestStr stringByAppendingString:@":8080/dblist.php?password="];
requestStr = [requestStr stringByAppendingString:passwordTextField.text];


NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestStr];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];


json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];


 DBList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 for (int i = 0; i < json.count; i++)
 {
 //Create the objects

 NSString * dbName = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Database"];


 //------------------------------------------

 Database * myDatabases = [[Database alloc]initWithDatabaseName: (NSString *) dbName];

 //Add the object to the array


 [DBList addObject:myDatabases];

 }

 [self.DBTable reloadData];
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, taking this word for word:

*"Essentially, if I see 'data parameter is nil' then I would like an alert to say "not able to connect, and return."*

```
if(data == nil)
{
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Problem" message:@"not able to connect" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];
     return;
}
else
{
    //The rest of your code
}
```

Comment: One additional question in relevance. So this works well if my hostTextField.text is wrong. But if it's correct (even with a wrong password) then it just loads nothing, and doesn't crash. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: FIXED: I added another alert after json.      if(json == nil)
         {
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camaleon Alert" message:@"Incorrect Host/Pass" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
             return;
         }
         else
         {